# Can JHispter generate more advanced Repository structure other than a flat one?

Tags: jhipster

Our app has ten similar entity classes with the shared attribute

```
boolean activated;
User user;
```

And a repository method

```
 Long countByActivatedTrueAndUser(User user);
```

is required for all of those repository interfaces.

In regular development, the following classes are likely created for this situation.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

  @Column(name = "activated")
  private Boolean activated;

  @ManyToOne
  private User user;

  public Boolean getActivated() {
    return activated;
  }

  public void setActivated(Boolean activated) {
    this.activated = activated;
  }

  public User getUser() {
    return user;
  }

  public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
  }
}

public interface BaseEntityRepository<T extends BaseEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {

  Long countByActivatedTrueAndUser(User user);

}

@Entity
public class Foo extends BaseEntity {

  // Foo-specific properties and methods
}

public interface FooRepository extends BaseEntityRepository<Foo> {

  // Foo-specific repository methods
}
```

In this fashion, the repository method is only needed to be defined once and applicable for all ten repositories.

Can JHipster do something similar other than a flat unrelated repositories?